# Why does most of the diagram of stateless microservice have the database inside the service and stateful microservice has external database?

Tags: microservices, state, stateless, stateful

Because as I understand it stateless micro service do not rely on state. So why does it need the database inside the micro-service? I thought it should be other way around.

I hope the location of database does not matter as long as the idea of the stateless is that the server will not store any session or any state but it will be stored in a database. While stateful ones do store session and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the diagrams related to Microservices architecture have database associated with a service. This is to display the fact that independent micro services have independent databases. In traditional monolith apps, the app would be connected to a single database. When we break a monolith into multiple micro services using domains, the ideal way is for each micro service to have a different database so that services can run and evolve independently. This is a true microservices architecture.

So, to answer your question, database in a micro service block in a diagram just shows the independence of the service with its own data model and logic.